# Ajax, JavaScript, PhP get value from a td and save it in an SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I get the value of a td, when I click on that spepcific td and save the value in an sql database. The table is build in this way:

```
$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" value="'.$current_day.'">';
$calendar.= '<p>Nurse: '.$nurse_number.' </p><p>Senior: '.$senior_number.' </p>';
$calendar.= '</td>';
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do a google search on ajax jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax. here is a sample code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

or if you use jquery this is the syntax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

for more info read: [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: Thank you hatzaviv for your quick answer! I am quite noob that is why I asked this noob question. The only thing is that the script is located in the php page, at the bottom. I want to take the value send to php and do something with it. Everything needs to happen in the same page! I have read a little bit about ajax, but honest to be I am looking for the easiest way to do it!

Comment: well that is just the way ajax works. php code happens before the page loads, and javascript happens after. so either you do everything with php or you could create a different php page with a function that does what you want and returns the data to the page, and then you can make the ajax request to the page and display the response.

Comment: The thing is that I will need to do with ajax cause I can't do it with any other, because I create dynamically a callendar(PHP) and when I click on a day I need to get the ID of the cell, store it and after to write in the cell some text.

Comment: You can use other methods for storing and getting cell id. Read about jQuery Data: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: Thank you, I will read about it and I will let you know if this resolved my problem :) !

Comment: Hi hatzaviv! I have read more about jquerry but I still don get it!I have this code. I want to get the value $current_day of the <td> when  I click it and to send it to a SQL database.  $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
  /* add in the day number */
  $calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><p hidden>'.$current_day.'</p><p>Nurse: </p><p>Senior: </p></div>';
  $calendar.= '</td>';

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're trying to get the value of a td. A td is not an input field I'm not sure you can assign a value to it. so the way I see it you have two options: either you put an input field inside the td and that way you can add a value to it. or instead of trying to get a value you can get the innerHTML of the td and you will get whatever is written there. A td is like a span or div.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$('td').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { value:$(this).attr('value') }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

Get value on some.php and save it to database.

M.

Comment: It is working, now  I have a problem saying "Notice: Undefined index: value in"    $date = $_POST['value'];

Comment: Actually it will send an json to some.php you can not get it with $_POST.
if you want to do same then use : data:'value'=$(this).attr('value').
This will work. if it helps dont forgot to accept answer.. Thnx